# XSD validations- combination of different values as one value

Tags: xml, xsd

I have several drop down options defined in xsd enum like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="allowedActionValues">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="*"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="none"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="CREATE"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="UPDATE"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="DELETE"/>
                </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But I want to allow this value too in my drop down- action="CREATE|UPDATE|DELETE"
One way is to add this value in enumeration
but I am looking for some other way where I can define any rule like- allow
any combination of defined values so that I don't have to add every such combination of my values in enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="allowedActionValues">
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="*"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="none"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="CREATE"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="UPDATE"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="DELETE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Then you can provide a list of any values from the enumeration separated with spaces:

```
<allowedActionValues>CREATE UPDATE DELETE</allowedActionValues>
```

Comment: Its working fine with spaces but when I am putting pipe operator as a dimiliter then its showing the following error:·         Cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'CREATE|UPDATE|DELETE' Is Not Facet-valid With Respect To Enumeration '[*, None, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE]'. It Must Be A Value From The Enumeration.. Line '52', Column '156'.
·         Cvc-attribute.3: The Value 'CREATE|UPDATE|DELETE' Of Attribute 'action' On Element 'DataObject' Is Not Valid With Respect To Its Type, 'allowedActionValues'.. Line '52', Column '156'.

Comment: @IshanRastogi Yes, you have to use spaces in XML to define lists. If you don't like that, you have to use two-stage validation, first validate against a schema that defines contents as `xs:string`, and if validated also validate the nodes programmatically to check if the contents makes sense.